# Что означает и откуда появилось слово "кирдык"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Что означает и откуда появилось слово "кирдык"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашла вот такое рассуждение. Имя автора высказывания, помещённого в "Татарской газете", и полный текст статьи [здесь](http://yuldash.com/tg/index.php?id=11612&pp=84&q=mes). Похоже, слово татарское.

"Глагол КЕРу/КИРу (в литературном произношении КыРу, в целом его смысл "срезать, снимать механически с какой-то поверхности что-то под корень", а также "уничтожать окончательно, истреблять") имел в давние времена и значение "резать" (позже в этом значении вытеснен его же формой КЕСу/КИСу). 
В момент заимствования слов "кердык/кирдык" означало, помимо нынешних значений литературного "кырдык" (побрили, скосили траву начисто, соскребли; уничтожили, истребили) означало еще и "зарезали, отрезали". Так что это слово было заимствовано русскими и практически не искажено за века пребывания в языке, так как достаточно хорошо укладывается в произносительные нормы русского языка".